# Position is undefined for Geolocation Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Hi I had just started learning aparche cordova. 
I am trying to connect a geolocation api to the application and had already installed geolocation api for cordova using `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation`
and am using the reference of the [apache-cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/index.html).
My JavaScript file is

```
// Listening for the device to be ready
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("navigator.geolocation should be able to run successfully now...");
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess,onError);
}
// onSuccess Callback
var onSuccess = function(position) {
    // current GPS coordinates
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        console.log('Geolocation is there '+ position);
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            alert('Latitude: '    + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
            'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
            'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
            'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
            'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
            'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
            'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
            'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
            }, function(error) {
                console.log('Error while connecting to geolocation ' + error)
            },
            {timeout:10000});
    }      
    else {
        console.log('Geolocation is not there');
    }
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

I am getting output on console as

> Geolocation is there undefined

ie., position = undefined.
and I am not getting any alert box when onSuccess event occurs.
The code works perfectly fine on ios but didnt work on Android/ browser

Comment: Whenever you have issues like that, the most likely reason is a missing permission in the app's manifest. You need to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` See also this: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html#runtime-permissions-cordova-android-500

Comment: I did add the the permission on android manifest     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> but  the alert box still dosent pop up

Comment: Did you follow this guide? http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html#android-permissions

Comment: @Chris G I also tried displaying latitudes on console using  console.log('Geolocation is there ' + position.coords.latitude); and the code ran into exception `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'coords' of undefined    at onSuccess (file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js:20:55)    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (file:///android_asset/www/index.html:22:58)"`

Comment: If `position` is already `undefined`, accessing `position.coords` will not work either. The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: Yes I did follow the guide

Comment: I am confused, if position is undefined then how come its working for ios??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147986/discussion-between-rishabh-sharma-and-chris-g).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. It is because in dev mode the url is: http//:192.168.0.105

Geolocation on mobile work when the url have ssl like **https**://192.168.0.105

You can make a fake certificate with:

https://blog.filippo.io/mkcert-valid-https-certificates-for-localhost/

For exemple, in **quasar framework** I set:

```
 devServer: {
      https: true,
      port: 8080,
      open: true // opens browser window automatically
    },
```

And this configuration solve my problem.